# use fillna(0) with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to replace NaN values with 0, but only when Type = u. How can I do it?

```
index Landsize    Type    
1       NaN         u      
2       NaN         m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Landsize'] = np.where(df['Type'] =='u', 0, np.nan)
```

or if not all values in `df['Landsize']` are `nan`:

```
df['Landsize'] = np.where(df['Type'] =='u', 0, df['Landsize'])
```

Comment: I've tried this and now almost all the values are 'NaN'.

Comment: Try this: `df['Landsize'] = np.where(df['Type'] =='u', 0, df['Landsize'])`

Answer (score -1):

try this:-

```
df[df['type']=='u']['Landsize'] = 0
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters

Comment: Solution is correct but not recommended that's different thing

Comment: ok, agree. Not  recommended.

Comment: btw, why not change it?

Comment: can do it  from next problems

Comment: @AniketDixit: why would you share a non-recommended solution? This can only generate trouble.